# I am trying to start using intellij as my IDE. I installed it in my PC and when I try to create the HelloWorld project basic it shows this error

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am trying to start using IntelliJ as my IDE. I installed it in my PC and when I try to create the HelloWorld project basic it shows this error :

Abnormal build process termination:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin\java.exe" -Xmx700m -Djava.awt.headless=true "-Djna.boot.library.path=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2023.2.1/lib/jna/amd64" -Djna.nosys=true -Djna.noclasspath=true --add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.model=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.parser=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.jvm=ALL-UNNAMED -Dcompile.parallel=false -Drebuild.on.dependency.change=true -Didea.IntToIntBtree.page.size=32768 -Djdt.compiler.useSingleThread=true -Daether.connector.resumeDownloads=false -Dio.netty.initialSeedUniquifier=1893346409506213830 -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -Duser.language=en -Duser.country=IN -Didea.paths.selector=IdeaIC2023.2 "-Didea.home.path=C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2023.2.1" -Didea.config.path=C:/Users/subra/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/IdeaIC2023.2 -Didea.plugins.path=C:/Users/subra/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/IdeaIC2023.2/plugins -Djps.log.dir=C:/Users/subra/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IdeaIC2023.2/log/build-log "-Djps.fallback.jdk.home=C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2023.2.1/jbr" -Djps.fallback.jdk.version=17.0.8 -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:/Users/subra/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IdeaIC2023.2/compile-server/untitled_cf19ab93/_temp_ -Djps.backward.ref.index.builder=true -Dtmh.instrument.annotations=true -Dtmh.generate.line.numbers=true "-Djps.kotlin.home=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2023.2.1\plugins\Kotlin\kotlinc" -Dkotlin.incremental.compilation=true -Dkotlin.incremental.compilation.js=true -Dkotlin.daemon.enabled -Dkotlin.daemon.client.alive.path=\"C:\Users\subra\AppData\Local\Temp\kotlin-idea-16534307499703245477-is-running\" -Dide.propagate.context=false -classpath "C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2023.2.1/plugins/java/lib/jps-launcher.jar" org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.Launcher "C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2023.2.1/plugins/java/lib/jps-builders.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2023.2.1/plugins/java/lib/jps-builders-6.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2023.2.1/plugins/java/lib/jps-javac-extension.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2023.2.1/lib/util-8.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2023.2.1/lib/util_rt.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2023.2.1/lib/platform-loader.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2023.2.1/lib/annotations.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2023.2.1/lib/protobuf.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2023.2.1/lib/jps-model.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2023.2.1/plugins/java/lib/javac2.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2023.2.1/lib/forms_rt.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2023.2.1/plugins/java/lib/aether-dependency-resolver.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2023.2.1/plugins/java/lib/maven-resolver-connector-basic.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2023.2.1/plugins/java/lib/maven-resolver-transport-file.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2023.2.1/plugins/java/lib/maven-resolver-transport-http.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2023.2.1/lib/idea_rt.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2023.2.1/plugins/Kotlin/lib/jps/kotlin-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2023.2.1/lib/util-8.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2023.2.1/plugins/devkit/lib/devkit-jps.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2023.2.1/plugins/devkit/lib/devkit-runtimeModuleRepository-jps.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2023.2.1/plugins/eclipse/lib/eclipse-jps.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2023.2.1/plugins/eclipse/lib/eclipse-common.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2023.2.1/plugins/ant/lib/ant-jps.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2023.2.1/plugins/platform-langInjection/lib/java-langInjection-jps.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2023.2.1/plugins/Groovy/lib/groovy-jps.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2023.2.1/plugins/Groovy/lib/groovy-constants-rt.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2023.2.1/plugins/javaFX/lib/javaFX-jps.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2023.2.1/plugins/javaFX/lib/javaFX-common.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2023.2.1/plugins/uiDesigner/lib/jps/java-guiForms-jps.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2023.2.1/plugins/space/lib/space-java-jps.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2023.2.1/plugins/maven/lib/maven-jps.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2023.2.1/plugins/gradle-java/lib/gradle-jps.jar" org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain 127.0.0.1 51295 5a765f89-75e1-45bf-93bc-b59ef1ea6c98 C:/Users/subra/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IdeaIC2023.2/compile-server
Be careful, logger will be shut down earlier than application: Unable to make field private static java.util.IdentityHashMap java.lang.ApplicationShutdownHooks.hooks accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @4e50df2e
Build process started. Classpath: C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2023.2.1/plugins/java/lib/jps-launcher.jar
Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:51295; reason: connection timed out: /127.0.0.1:51295
io.netty.channel.ConnectTimeoutException: connection timed out: /127.0.0.1:51295
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe$1.run(AbstractNioChannel.java:261)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.PromiseTask.runTask(PromiseTask.java:98)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledFutureTask.java:153)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.runTask(AbstractEventExecutor.java:174)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:167)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:470)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:569)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Exiting.
```

I need to develop the projects using IntelliJ. Someone help me resolve this issue.
I have set:

- path variable to JDK-17/bin
- Java home to JDK 17

Comment: Does it help if you disable the firewall/security software or disconnect from the VPN? Something is blocking localhost connections on your system. Check /etc/hosts file on your system

Comment: Hi, I have disabled the firewall and I couldn't find anything blocking localhost.  can you help me on this. Its been quite some time. I have followed all kinds of tutorials on how to install and use intellij and java, but of no use. can you please help me